# Comparing three large very large arrays and creating a new object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, foreach, compare

Alright, so I have three arrays with about 65k objects in each in node.js. They all share an ID - PARCELID, SBL, and SBL20 are the same. I want to combine the objects from the different arrays into a single object that is then pushed into the final array. For whatever reason, the output I get contains 130k+ objects. This is also pretty inefficient so if there is a better way to do this, I am all ears - I have attempted to use map() though I was only able to compare two arrays, not three. I have a fourth I would like to add into the mix as well.

```html
var final = new Array();
  count=0
  TaxParcels.forEach((TaxParcel) => {
    TaxBills.forEach((TaxBill) => {
      if (TaxParcel.PARCELID == TaxBill.SBL20) {
        CodeEnforcements.forEach((CodeEnforcement) => {
          if (TaxParcel.PARCELID == CodeEnforcement.SBL) {
            parcel = {
              ID: TaxParcel.PARCELID,
              DETAILS: {
                TaxParcel: TaxParcel,
                TaxBill: TaxBill,
                CodeEnforcement: CodeEnforcement,
              },
            };
            final.push(parcel);
            count++
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(final);
  console.log(count)
```

Comment: *"For whatever reason, the output I get contains 130k+ objects."*: this means you have duplicate ID values in the same input array. Please provide sample (small, dummy) input, with expected output.

Comment: Can confirm no duplicate ID values. Once I was finally able to find a JSON viewer that can handle 200MB+ JSON files, I discovered that it is pushing each true statement to the array four times.

Comment: If you want that explained, show a reproducible case (code & data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get performance gain by first creating a Map, keyed by the keys, with empty objects related to each. Then inject the objects into those objects, and filter the result to only have objects with all 3 keys:

```js
// sample data
let TaxParcels = [{ PARCELID: 3 }, { PARCELID: 9 }, { PARCELID: 7 }];
let TaxBills = [{ SBL20: 9 }, { SBL20: 1 }, { SBL20: 3 }];
let CodeEnforcements = [{ SBL: 3 }, { SBL: 9 }, { SBL: 1 }];

// Solution
let map = new Map([...TaxParcels, ...TaxBills, ...CodeEnforcements].map(o => 
    [o.PARCELID??o.SBL20??o.SBL, {}])
);

for (let o of TaxParcels) map.get(o.PARCELID).TaxParcel = o;
for (let o of TaxBills) map.get(o.SBL20).TaxBill = o;
for (let o of CodeEnforcements) map.get(o.SBL).CodeEnforcement = o;

let result = [...map.values()].filter(o => Object.keys(o).length === 3);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```

Comment: This is way more efficient and provided the correct output as well. Re: [o.PARCELID??o.SBL20??o.SBL, {}]) - What do the question marks mean in this context? Also, I've never seen the use of "..." before. Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like the format of the array returned by map is formatted in the first line, we then set the relevant objects to o?

Comment: Also, I've never seen the use of "..." before. Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like the format of the array returned by map is formatted in the first line, we then set the relevant objects to o. (Sorry, edited original comment).

Comment: `...` is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). You can use `concat` instead. Not sure what you are saying about Map.

Comment: Doesn't map create a new array with results? So we are formatting the array with [o.PARCELID??o.SBL20??o.SBL, {}]) and then we inject those values with for (let o of TaxParcels) map.get(o.PARCELID).TaxParcel = o;
for (let o of TaxBills) map.get(o.SBL20).TaxBill = o;
for (let o of CodeEnforcements) map.get(o.SBL).CodeEnforcement = o;

Comment: Just to explain the `Map` constructor: it accepts an argument that must be an array of pairs (arrays of 2). So like `[ [1, {}], [2, {}], [3, {}] ]`. The `Map` constructor will create a `Map` object from that using keys 1, 2 and 3 (in this example), and the values sit next to it in each pair. The `.map` call is creating this array of pairs.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and maybe not most significant) way is to avoid `forEach` here: it iterates over the whole arrays pointlessly even after the element is found. There is no way to break `forEach`. It may be replaced with `for-of` loops with `break` or with `find` array methods. This will also eliminate duplicates. The last way example:

```js
const TaxParcels = [{ PARCELID: 1}, { PARCELID: 2}, { PARCELID: 3}];
const TaxBills = [{ SBL20: 1}, { SBL20: 2}, { SBL20: 3}];
const CodeEnforcements = [{ SBL: 1}, { SBL: 2}, { SBL: 3}];

const final = [];
let count=0;

for (const TaxParcel of TaxParcels) {
  const ID = TaxParcel.PARCELID;

  const TaxBill = TaxBills.find(({ SBL20 }) => SBL20 === ID);
  const CodeEnforcement = CodeEnforcements.find(({ SBL }) => SBL === ID);

  if (TaxBill && CodeEnforcement) {
    count++;
    final.push({ ID, DETAILS: { TaxParcel, TaxBill, CodeEnforcement } });
  }
}

console.log(count);
console.log(JSON.stringify(final, null, '  '));
```

But maybe the most significant improvement is to use more appropriate id-keyed structures as in other answer here.

Comment: This is great, however performance gain from the chosen answer is remarkably better. Thank you for the help! Will definitely organize like this in the future - probably doesn't help that I've pulled an all-nighter...6AM...need sleep.